# Не могу заставить телеграм бота отправлять сообщения

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Работаю с библиотекой Telebot для Python. Хочу что бы бот отправлял сообщения сам в определенное время дня. В интернете нашел только одно решение(прикрепил скрин). Для этого нужен chat_id(id чата), но я не понимаю где его искать[image: введите сюда описание изображения](Пытался разобраться сам - не получается)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: код с вашего скриншота не будет отправлять сообщения `сам в определенное время дня`

Answer (score 0):

Chat_id можно получить из сообщения отправленного пользователем. В вашем случае можете создать базу данных с id пользователей, которым нужно отправить сообщение и в определённый момент смотреть по БД айди и создавать рассылку. Но вы не сможете отправлять сообщения пользователям, которые не написали ни одного сообщения в ваш бот.

Comment: Спасибо. А можете по подробнее рассказать, как именно получить айди из сообщения?

Comment: @Egor учитесь Гуглить.
По первой ссылке найти можно:
`message.chat.id`

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.message_handler()  # в скобках состояние, переменная или команда
def hello(message: Message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Привет!')  # можно использовать message.from_user.id вместо message.chat.id
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять более развёрнутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit].